# to fetch the data's from website from 00.00 - 7.00AM(EST) IN PYTHON datetimerange using between condition

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, timezone, datetimerangefield

```
published_date = 7/11/2019 at 06:04 AM,7/11/2019 at 1:04 AM,7/11/2019 at 5:36 AM,7/11/2019 at 04:00 PM
```

All times are in EST. 
I need to fetch data from time range of `00.00 - 07.00 AM(EST)`.It should skip the time above `7.00AM(EST)`

if published_date.time() <= 7:00AM
                        print(published_date.time())

Actual results:

```
published_date = 7/11/2019 at 06:04 AM,7/11/2019 at 1:04 AM,7/11/2019 at 5:36 AM,7/11/2019 at 04:00 PM
```

Expected results:

```
published_date = 7/11/2019 at 06:04 AM,7/11/2019 at 1:04 AM,7/11/2019 at 5:36 AM
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: if published_date.time() <= 7:00AM I culdnt know how to fetch time range using between condition

Comment: Can you paste your code in your question?

Comment: if published_date.time() <= 7:00AM
                        print(published_date.time()) code is above

Comment: `published_date` is what type of variable? Convert it to datetime object (e.g. with `strptime()` if `string` originally), then you can select ranges with conditionals like `if published_date.hour >= 7`

Comment: type of published_date is <type 'datetime.datetime'>

Comment: (e.g. with strptime() if string originally) can u tell this logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date are not in correct format. Hence it will not parse and compare it correct. You need to use `datetime` library to convert the strings into date and compare. 
Here is the working example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
checkTime = dt.time(7,0,0)
published_dates = ["7/11/2019 06:04 AM","7/11/2019 1:04 AM","7/11/2019 5:36 AM","7/11/2019 04:00 PM"]
filtered_dates = []
for d in published_dates:
  dt1 = datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
  if (dt1.time() < checkTime):
      filtered_dates.append(dt1.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p"))
print('filtered_dates : ', filtered_dates)
```

Comment: fr time range between 7AM-12PM what will be the condition it shuld inculde 7AM datas too

Comment: If you want to fetch datetime between a timerange, use condition like `7 < time< 12`. P.S. datetime hours are in 24 hour format.

Comment: How can I chnge in the above logic what will be the checktime

Comment: Add if confition as `if( checkTime < dt1.time()) and (dt1.time() < dt.time(12,0,0)):
     range_dates.append(dt1.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p"))`  Here is the example : https://repl.it/repls/ModernPriceyScreenscraper

Comment: for the timerange between 12pm to 11:59pm if( checkTime < dt1.time()) and (dt1.time() < dt.time(11,59,0)) and checkTime = dt.time(12,0,0) is this crct